# Inject anything other than param value

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to inject anything other than values using the `@Query` N1QL query syntax but can't get it to work.

Here is the pure N1QL query:

```
SELECT * from `my-bucket` WHERE _class = 'my.package.MyModel' AND myParam = 'myValue'
```

I successfully manage to inject **a value** in Java and get the correct results:

```
// In my repository
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE myParam = $1 AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
Collection<MyModel> myCustomSearch(String value);
// In my business code
myRepository.myCustomSearch("myValue");
```

However I can't manage to inject **anything else (like a param)**. This doesn't work:

```
// In my repository
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE $1 = 'myValue' AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
Collection<MyModel> myCustomSearch(String param);
// In my business code
myRepository.myCustomSearch("myParam");
```

Considering that in a pure N1QL query, the value usually is wrapped in single quotes ('') and it's not necessary when injecting it, I'm afraid spring-data-couchbase always wraps injected elements with single or double quotes (thus my query is transformed into

```
SELECT * from `my-bucket` WHERE _class = 'my.package.MyModel' AND 'myParam' = 'myValue'
```

which explains why Couchbase doesn't return any result).

Did I miss something? Otherwise, is there a way to bypass the quote injection from spring-data-couchbase?

I am aware I could simply use a `com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket` and call `query` on it, but this loses the whole point of spring-data-couchbase for me, which is to always manipulate POJOs and hide the JSON manipulation.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` is actually just using the N1QL syntax for parameterized statements. I haven't extensively tested it, but you could use SpEL here. The way to use a method parameter in SpEL is to use the `#{[x]}` syntax where `x` is the 0-based index of the parameter to use.

Careful when mixing the two approaches though: as soon as a `$x` is detected in the statement, Spring Data Couchbase will use **all** method arguments as the array to populate $x placeholders. So the first argument will map to `$1`, the second to `$2`, etc...

So to use both syntax (one to dynamically choose a field name, the other to let N1QL inject the searched value) you'd have to write something like:

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{[0]} = $2 AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
public List<Entity> findAllBySomeCriteria(String fieldName, String value);
```

Notice how `#{[0]}` and `$1` will both point to the `fieldName` parameter, so the N1QL placeholder used is `$2`, that points to `value`.

Comment: I'm curious, where did you find this `#{[]}` syntax? I haven't seen it anywhere on the spring-data-couchbase or SpEL documentations such a feature/syntax.

Comment: found it in Spring Data JPA documentation IIRC, while googling for SpEL method parameter support. I just added the syntax and example to the Spring Data Couchbase documentation in [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/commit/415d8a2d2386f4387df95f54ff4a92467d57f7db)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation update, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: See @simon-baslé 's answer, even shorter and more elegant than mine.

---

I think I found the best solution for my needs, in the form of [implementing a custom method in my repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#_couchbase_specifics_about_adding_methods_to_a_single_repository).

```
public interface MyRepositoryCustom {
  Collection<MyModel> customN1qlQuery(String query); 
}

public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyModel, String>, MyRepositoryCustom { } 

public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepositoryCustom { 

  @Autowired
  RepositoryOperationsMapping templateProvider; 

  @Override
  public Collection<MyModel> customN1qlQuery(String query) {
    CouchbaseOperations template = templateProvider.resolve(MyRepository.class, MyModel.class);
    return template.findByN1QL(N1qlQuery.simple(query), MyModel.class);
  }
}

// In my business code
Collection<MyModel> result = myRepository.customN1qlQuery("select META().id AS _ID, META().cas AS _CAS, * from `" + bucket.name() + "` where _class = '"
            + MyModel.class.getCanonicalName() + "' and " + myCustomParam + " = '" + myCustomValue + "'");
```

I keep manipulating POJOs, yet I have full control over the N1QL query statement. The only (minor) drawback is that I can no longer inject [Spring SpEL syntax](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.n1ql) (like `#{#n1ql.selectEntity}` to retrieve the full entity, or `#{#n1ql.filter}` to filter on the entity class name). I found literal equivalent (as shown in my example above), so I can live with that.

Comment: You can also use the methods in `N1qlUtils`, these are used by the framework to construct parts of the DSL that correspond to the Couchbase SpEL elements.